# Calendar setting on my iphone 5s

Tags: iphone

How do I set up my iphone 5s so that it shows all my calenders (home and office) but does not put my home calendar entries on my calendar at my office?

Comment: A few more details may get you a better answer - are these iCloud Calendars? What are you using to access and display your calendar at your office? Is the problem that new calendar entries are getting added to the wrong calendar? or do you simply need to not display your home calendar at the office?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default calendar for new entries added on your iPhone.

To do so on your iPhone, go to Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> Default Calendar (at the very bottom). There, choose your Home calendar and all new entries will be added to that calendar by default.